# I am gone. This is not my place

Tags: discussion

I might come back one day when moderators enforce that claims are underlain with references and psychopaths are restrained to reasonable content and kept from spreading bunk.

This site only costs time, there is nothing in it for someone who isn't after reputation points. I get my kicks elsewhere.

To those few who keep up the banner of science, you're awesome !

Cheers, and hang loose

ebv

Comment: Have you looked at [*Shall we have a “cite your sources” policy for answers?*](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22/6)?

Comment: We'd be sorry to see you go.  Would you mind postponing your departure and take part in this discussion: [*Do we need to be stricter on enforcing citations?*](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1818/6)?

Comment: As for restraining users — we're sorry you are made to feel unwelcome.  We do not generally comment on individual users but unacceptable behaviour can and has led to warnings and will, if it continues, lead to suspensions.  We hope you decide to stay or, if not, decide to come back and try again, otherwise we understand, thank you for your contributions, and wish you well in the future.

Comment: @Universal_learner: I am not after the rep, I thought i had made that clear :-) And maybe i give it a try. Will focus on staying away from trouble.

Comment: ebv don't leave please. Moderator/s are solving the particular issue we have, but it looks no so simple to solve. gerrit post about our policy with answers with no citation is a good start for an open discussion in general about our policy. Consider we are still a beta site.

Comment: Totally understand @ebv we really need to improve the quality of discussion, and work on making the quality of answers rigorous and factually accurate. There are too many off topic comments and hand-waving arguments. Hope you'll consider coming back one day

Comment: Okok. The flare is over. Before all, i can learn something here.

Comment: It seems this user suicided

Answer (score 6):

My goodness, 22 well-received posts (mostly answers) in your first 27 days suggests that you are really engaging with the site and finding something good here!

I'd recommend that you just ignore numerical reputation altogether. Most users end up doing that. Personally I think it should be displayed in base-10 log like pH, so 1000 = 3, 100k = 5, etc.

You seem to be just the kind of user that makes a Stack Exchange community thrive! I'd put "Let Stack Exchange be Stack Exchange" in my profile a few years ago when I realized that I'll never understand what it is, but that it somehow works well enough even though it's wide open to the internet and anybody can participate.

Please consider staying around a little longer and continue engaging on a scientific basis. 27 days may simply not be long enough to get used to SE's quirky but ultimately satisfying nature.

Just ignore the stuff you don't like. If you disagree with something, leave a comment and move on to the next interesting thing. There are [almost 200 different SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest) so consider expanding out into to other areas and other communities as well. Each is unique.

Comment: I am NOT after the rep and i have more than enough interesting things from the real world right before me. The site costs too much time if done carefully, in opposition to the casual posters who fire off high frequency low quality content, scoff at others, lie, manipulate, evade clarification and mess up basic physical processes.

Comment: @ebv I don't notice those casual posters so much, but if you can't find away to focus on them less, then... okay.

Answer (score 4):

I hope you read this @ebv and you consider returning.

I am gonna be clear, as I don't want more valuable users lost.

I have talked with a moderator about the issue you are angry with. Moderators are solving the issue, I don't know how, but there is some private emailing we are not seeing.

Their account has been suspended a day. On physics exchange they were suspended 1 month and never returned.

Please consider that moderators task is done for free and it is sometimes difficult. This site needs to be welcoming with every user and mods need to be exemplary.

I can't read those emails, but if the user doesn't changes their behaviour I guess finally there are more severe penalties possible.

I hope you can return once the issue is solved. We appreciate your also high activity, but with rigorous science.

Thanks for the time you got to answer some of our questions in any case, contributing to our library of knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

**There is something: the reward of helping others. It should be enough.** Although I admit it's kind of exciting to see the little number going up...

I agree that the reputation system creates some issues. It's been debated for a while: see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation) from almost 10 years ago, pointing the problem of "extrinsic motivation" (i.e. rep points).

See also [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252077#252077) dividing the community into four categories: (1) caretakers, (2) vampires, (3) repwhores, and (4) apathics". You are a 1, so you hate 3. In the end, you give up. Congratulations, you are now a 4! :]